# R:Smooth scatter plot creating specific color for values

Tags: r, plot, scatter-plot

Hello I have created smooth scatter plot colored based on the data category,now I am not getting which color represent which category so for understanding if I pass specific color to each category it will look more convenient according to that how can I do this `col=df$cat` its not color specific points it belongs I am not understanding any one suggest me

specific color to each category for example data1=green, data2=blue, data3=black, data4=red

my data

```
   A    B   cat
 0.8803 0.0342  data1
 0.9174 0.0331  data1
 0.9083 0.05    data1
 0.7542 0.161   data2
 0.8983 0.0593  data2
 0.8182 0.1074  data2
 0.3525 0.3525  data3
 0.5339 0.2288  data3
 0.7295 0.082   data3
 0.8    0.0417  data4
 0.8291 0.0598  data4
 0.8    0.025   data4
```

script which I have tried

```
df=read.table("test.txt", sep='\t', header=TRUE)
smoothScatter(df$B,df$A,,nrpoints=Inf,xlim=c(0,1),ylim=c(0,1), pch=20,cex=1, col=df$cat)
points(c(0,1),c(1,0),type='l',col='green',lty=2,lwd=2)
legend(0.30, 1, c("diagonal"), 
       col = c("green"), 
       lty = 2, lwd = 4)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create the colors vector as a named vector. Then plot with `x=A`, `y=B` and, in `geom_point` only, `color=cat`. The diagonal line is drawn by a `geom_line` call with a new `data` argument, the end points of the line.

```
library(ggplot2)

color <- c(data1="green", data2="blue", data3="black", data4="red")

ggplot(df, aes(A, B)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = cat), alpha = 0.25) +
  geom_line(
    data = data.frame(A = 0:1, B = 1:0),
    mapping = aes(A, B),
    color = "green",
    linetype = "dashed"
  ) +
  scale_color_manual(values = color) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

---

### Base R

With `smoothScatter` the graph is as follows.

```
colnum <- match(df$cat, names(color))

smoothScatter(
  df$B, df$A,
  nrpoints = Inf,
  xlim = c(0, 1), ylim = c(0, 1), 
  pch = 20, cex = 1, 
  col = color[colnum]
)
points(c(0, 1), c(1, 0), type = 'l', col = 'green', lty = 2, lwd = 2)
legend(0.30, 1, "diagonal", col = "green", lty = 2, lwd = 4)
```

[image]

Or, if we remove `nrpoints = Inf`

```
smoothScatter(
  df$B, df$A,
  #nrpoints = Inf,
  xlim = c(0, 1), ylim = c(0, 1), 
  pch = 20, cex = 1, 
  col = color[colnum]
)
points(c(0, 1), c(1, 0), type = 'l', col = 'green', lty = 2, lwd = 2)
legend(0.30, 1, "diagonal", col = "green", lty = 2, lwd = 4)
```

[image]

### Data

```
google_id <- "1FN0H7ilY9OwcQC7Y8iiLUZd2CTuJ9U4Z"
google_file <- sprintf("https://docs.google.com/uc?id=%s&export=download", google_id)
df <- read.table(google_file, header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks but when try this on my entire dataset its not working i know exactly were my values falling I tried with this data https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FN0H7ilY9OwcQC7Y8iiLUZd2CTuJ9U4Z/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Even I tried with single values for each category gave different color which is not matching

Comment: @Luckysardar I have changed to `ggplot`, see the edit.

Comment: @Luckysardar Also, I have tried to match the colors with the data using my previous code and it worked, but like this `ggplot` will do it automatically.

Comment: I have tried ggplot its showing exactly what I wanted, the problem is I wanted the previous plot please show me the plot and code how its looking, i my case it not looking same

Comment: have to create one more points(c(0,0.90),c(0.90,0)) this I have tried with ggplot not able get I am getting in smooth scatter plot so I  wanted older one

Comment: @Luckysardar See the edit. Is this what you want?

Comment: you can see smooth scatter plot and ggplot which are not looking similar, smooth  plot color pattern should look like ggplot

Comment: @Luckysardar Yes, I saw that. It seems that the graphs are symmetric of one another. I don't know how `smoothScatter` places the points but `ggplot` is right.

Comment: yes, I don't understand why is like that but still I am accepting your ans some how it helped Thank you